# YQLで全てのTicker シンボルを取得する方法

Tags: api

海外の株式マーケットのTickerシンボル一覧が欲しく探してみたところ
YQLで取得が可能だという情報を見つけたのですが、試してみても検索結果が0になってしまいます。

具体的には

```
select * from yahoo.finance.industry where id in (select industry.id from yahoo.finance.sectors)
```

の結果が

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 0,
  "created": "2015-05-03T07:01:26Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "url": [
    {
     "execution-start-time": "1",
     "execution-stop-time": "5",
     "execution-time": "4",
     "content": "http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.industry.xml"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "6",
     "execution-stop-time": "8",
     "execution-time": "2",
     "content": "http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.sectors.xml"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "15",
     "execution-stop-time": "35",
     "execution-time": "20",
     "content": "http://biz.yahoo.com/ic/ind_index.html"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "15",
     "execution-stop-time": "35",
     "execution-time": "20",
     "content": "http://biz.yahoo.com/ic/ind_index.html"
    }
   ],
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "query": {
    "execution-start-time": "12",
    "execution-stop-time": "51",
    "execution-time": "39",
    "params": "{url=[http://biz.yahoo.com/ic/ind_index.html]}",
    "content": "select * from html where url=@url and xpath='//td[@width=\"50%\"]/table/tr/td'"
   },
   "javascript": {
    "execution-start-time": "11",
    "execution-stop-time": "51",
    "execution-time": "40",
    "instructions-used": "12000",
    "table-name": "yahoo.finance.sectors"
   },
   "user-time": "52",
   "service-time": "38",
   "build-version": "0.2.450"
  },
  "results": null
 }
}
```

になってしまいます。

コードの実行は[こちら](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.industry%20where%20id%20in%20(select%20industry.id%20from%20yahoo.finance.sectors))で、また元のコードは[本家Stackoverflowの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246843/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-ticker-symbols-from-yahoo-finance)から使わせてもらっています。

すでにこのコードは使えなくなっているのでしょうか？
それとも何か実行の方法が間違っていますか？